# pdr. Datareader - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: pandas, typeerror, datareader

This code worked just fine until today.
Now i get this Error message:  TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
Equity_Indices = ['^GSPC', 'ES=F', 'NQ=F', 'YM=F', '^RUT', '^DJT', 
                  '^GDAXI', '^N225', '^SSMI', '^STOXX50E', '^FCHI', 
                  '^GSPTSE', '^HSI', '000001.SS', '^KS11', '^NSEI', '^AXJO']
Equity_Indices_df = pdr.DataReader(Equity_Indices, 'yahoo', start='1990-01-01', end='today')
```

What happened? I am kinda lost here.

I am completely lost, I did not change a thing. this code worked just fine yesterday.

Comment: Your question was about how to solve this issue. You forced a deletion of a solution. State clearly in your question that your re not looking for alternatives.

Comment: I was one of the people who downvoted the solution because I had the exact same question today and didn't find the answer of importing another library adequate w/o an explanation why.  I don't know SO's actual policy, but judging from the many answers, it's common and expected to explain the reasoning for a particular solution.  If you add that explanation to the answer, I will find it helpful and will upvote the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if you absolutely must use `pandas_datareader` you will need to downgrade it to:

```
pip install pandas_datareader==0.9.0
```

Your code will run

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr 
import timedelta
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

Equity_Indices = ['^GSPC', 'ES=F', 'NQ=F', 'YM=F', '^RUT', '^DJT', '^GDAXI', '^N225', '^SSMI', '^STOXX50E', '^FCHI', '^GSPTSE', '^HSI', '000001.SS', '^KS11', '^NSEI', '^AXJO']

print(pdr.__version__)
from datetime import datetime
startdate = '1990-01-01'
today = date.today()
enddate = today

dd = []
for symbol in Equity_Indices:
    try:
        Equity_Indices_df = pdr.DataReader(symbol,'yahoo',startdate,enddate)
        print(Equity_Indices_df.head(5))
        dd.append(Equity_Indices_df)
    except:
        print('did not find: '+symbol)
```

but will return:

```
did not find: ^GSPC
did not find: ES=F
did not find: NQ=F
did not find: YM=F
did not find: ^RUT
did not find: ^DJT
did not find: ^GDAXI
did not find: ^N225
did not find: ^SSMI
did not find: ^STOXX50E
did not find: ^FCHI
did not find: ^GSPTSE
did not find: ^HSI
did not find: 000001.SS
did not find: ^KS11
did not find: ^NSEI
did not find: ^AXJO
```

This means that `Yahoo` has changed something on the page from which to retreive symbol data.

Today, the only fix is to do the following:

You need to use `y_finance` and use `pdr_overide()`

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from datetime import datetime,date

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

y_symbols = ['^GSPC', 'ES=F', 'NQ=F', 'YM=F', '^RUT', '^DJT', '^GDAXI', '^N225', '^SSMI', '^STOXX50E', '^FCHI', '^GSPTSE', '^HSI', '000001.SS', '^KS11', '^NSEI', '^AXJO']

from datetime import datetime
startdate = datetime(1990,1,1)
today = date.today()
enddate = today


data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(y_symbols, start=startdate, end=enddate)
```

which returns:

```
print(data.head(2)

   Adj Close                                                           \
           000001.SS ES=F NQ=F YM=F ^AXJO ^DJT ^FCHI       ^GDAXI       ^GSPC   
Date                                                                            
1990-01-02       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  1788.890015  359.690002   
1990-01-03       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  1867.290039  358.760010   

                         ... Volume                                          \
                ^GSPTSE  ... ^GDAXI        ^GSPC   ^GSPTSE ^HSI ^KS11 ^N225   
Date                     ...                                                  
1990-01-02  3994.230957  ...    0.0  162070000.0  164600.0  0.0   NaN   NaN   
1990-01-03  3999.317871  ...    0.0  192330000.0  147600.0  0.0   NaN   NaN   

                                               
           ^NSEI         ^RUT ^SSMI ^STOXX50E  
Date                                           
1990-01-02   NaN  162070000.0   NaN       NaN  
1990-01-03   NaN  192330000.0   NaN       NaN  

[2 rows x 102 columns]
```

Comment: I would prefer to keep using datareader, as I said it worked perfectly fine just until today. I have been using this code for months. Did something change in the way datareader connects to yahoo?

Answer (score 2):

My code has also stopped working.

It appears that yahoo has changed their interface. In the immortal words of Dr. McCoy: "I know engineers. They love to change things."

I've made the following changes to my code:

```
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()

df = yf.download(ticker, dateStart, dateEnd)
```

This has created another minor nuisance, the columns come in a different order now. Whereas before they were:

```
Date, High, Low, Open, Close, Volume, Adj Close
```

They are now:

```
Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume
```

This shouldn't be a problem unless you're hardcoding all your column code, so beware.

I haven't done any benchmarks, but the download feels faster.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was banging my head against a brick wall for a number of hours before I got to your answer. Works a treat! :-)

Comment: [data.reindex(columns=cols)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44189404/15893581)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Tried fetching past 5 years data.

```
import yfinance as yf

from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()
today
end_date = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date
d1 = date.today() - timedelta(days=360*5) #for last 5 years
d1
start_date = d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_date
data = yf.download(tickers = "GOOGL",
                  start = start_date,
                  end = end_date)
data.shape
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

corrections for `yahoo`

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import yfinance as yf       # install & import yfinance
import datetime as dt

yf.pdr_override()       # use pdr_override to get yahoo

Equity_Indices = ['^GSPC', 'ES=F']
s= '2010-1-1'
e= dt.datetime.today()     #can use explicit .strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# refer to pdr.data. to avoid TypeError: string indices must be integers
_df = pdr.data.get_data_yahoo(Equity_Indices,  start= s, end= e)['Adj Close']  
print(_df.tail())
```

`FRED` stuff is OK

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr    # 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
print(pdr.__version__)

f1 = 'TEDRATE' # ted spread (LT ind.)
f2 = 'T10Y2Y' # constant maturity ten yer - 2 year
f3 = 'T10Y3M' # constant maturity 10yr - 3m

tr = pdr.DataReader( [f1, f2, f3],  "fred", '1/1/10', dt.datetime.today())
print(tr.head())
tr.plot(grid = True) # Plot 
plt.show()
```